# Cyclic numbering of graph in Python

Tags: python, networkx

How do I assign cyclic numbers to graph vertices and generate adjacency matrix corresponding to it? The current and desired output is attached.

```
import networkx as nx
n = 5
p = 0.8
G = nx.generators.random_graphs.gnp_random_graph(n, p)
nx.draw(G)

A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
T=A.toarray()
print(T)
```

*Current output*
[image]

*Desired output*
[image]

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have shown?

Comment: It doesn't display the number of the vertices...

Comment: What does it display instead?

Comment: I have edited the post. The current output is included now.

Answer (score 0):

Your have to activate labels with the keyword `with_labels=True`. The function `nx.draw()` accepts all keywords of the function [`draw_networkx`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html?highlight=draw_networkx#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx), but has different default values.

**Example**

```
import networkx as nx
n = 5
p = 0.8
G = nx.generators.random_graphs.gnp_random_graph(n, p)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)

A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
T=A.toarray()
print(T)
```

**Example Output**

[image]